# Event on GridView scroll end

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-gridview, android-scroll

I want to change some layout parameter dynamically when I reached last element of GridView. 
my gridView contains 50 elements so when user start scrolling from 1 line, and when user reach last element i want to change some layout parameter. and when user scroll  up that changed parameter back to original value.